# Rendering a v2 form from Preside formbuilder

Tags: coldfusion

I'm stuck in rendering a v2 form that I created using Preside formbuilder.

so far I have:

```
args.newsletter = formbuilderService.getForm("[id]");
args.rendered = formbuilderService.renderForm(
            formId = args.newsletter.id,
            layout = "default",
            validationResult = "");
```

but all I get from `args.rendered` is:

```
<div class="formbuilder-form form form-horizontal"> <div class="alert alert-success"></div> </div>
```

But I want to render the whole form, like if I would add it by using a widget.

Comment: Does `renderWidget` helper help in your case?

Comment: @ThumChoonTat I'm using preside, does that contain renderWidget? I'm new to it

Answer (score 0):

`FormbuilderService.renderForm` expects the `configuration` argument to contain data from the form builder widget in order to render the form correctly.

You can use the `renderWidget` helper to render the form

```
args.newsletter = formbuilderService.getForm( "[id]" );
args.rendered   = renderWidget(
      widgetId = "formbuilderForm"
    , config   = {
          form       = args.newsletter
        , layout     = "default"
        , instanceid = ""
    }
);
```